# Place minor pages in the right place in the TOC

Tags: python-sphinx, sections, read-the-docs, toctree

In my sphinx documentation, I have some minor pages that (of course) need to be part of the toctree, but I can't get them listed in the right place.

If my "section 3" page looks like so:

```
.. toctree::
   3.3
   3.4

3
=====



3.1
-----


3.2
---
```

Then `3.3` and `3.4` are listed *before* `3`.

I've tried other permutations, but none seem to work.

1. If I put the toctree after the `3` heading then `3.3` and `3.4` are listed *between* `3` and `3.1`.
2. If I put the toctree at the end of the page, everything is in the right order, but `3.3` and `3.4` become third-level sections, children of section `3.2`.

---

I've put up a concrete example, here:

- http://sphinx-problem.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- https://github.com/bukzor/sphinx-problem

Answer (score 0):

To get  the general structure right, you can user the [include directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) as follows:

```
3
=====

3.1
-----

3.2
---

.. include:: 3_3.rst

.. include:: 3_4.rst
```

Still, there is no good way to have these sections listed in a toctree on the same page. Listing `self` in the toctree will only show the first level heading and a direct self-reference - in your example to `further-detail-1` - will work for html (although it will cause a warning), but mess up the `latexpdf` build.

As a workaround, you could simply hard-code your own toctree using a list of [references](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations).