# Is it possible to mix external links and includes in the toctree (ordered)?

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I need to include the page content and some external links in the `toctree` of my sphinx documentation, in the correct order

Suppose this is my structure:

```
=======
Test
=======

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   Test <http:://stackoverflow.com>

Some text

.. include page1.rst
.. include page2.rst
```

Then the resulting toctree is

- Test
- Page1
- Page2

But I need it to be

- Page1
- Page2
- Test

So, I need a way to either change the order of the toctree, or to add the included pages manually to the toctree, which would be fine as well.

The only "solution" I came up with at the moment is to include dummy-documents. But that results in a not so nice navigation path for the users.

*Note: This question is partly related to this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659349/sphinx-place-minor-pages-in-the-right-place-in-the-toc/35672388#35672388](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659349/sphinx-place-minor-pages-in-the-right-place-in-the-toc/35672388#35672388_)*